# Process [#] terminated with status [#]

Tags: process

What is "process [number in parentheses] terminated with status 1"?  or "with status 99"?

I forget exactly where it appeared. Probably in a crash report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers you have pointed out are referred to as exit status value of a process. If a process terminates properly then the exit status will always be 0, if it does not terminate properly then the exit status will be some number other than 0.

You can found the exit status of the last executed command by running the following in the terminal:

```
echo $?
```

Here is an example:

```
$ lsb_release -sc
trusty
$ echo $?
0
```

The execution was a success indicated by the value 0.

```
$ lsb_releasedd
lsb_releasedd: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

The command was not found hence unsuccessful indicated by the value 127.

Comment: Thanks. (that was a 17-character-long comment, including the reference to the user mentioned :D )

Comment: @aksub: As my answer serves the query then please select it as the right answer to your question so that others can be notified that the question has been answered.

Comment: Got it.  Done.  But why didn't my reference to you appear on my comment as your reference to me did?

Comment: @aksub: Post it again.

Comment: @aksub: It should..anyway if you want you can paste it in http://paste.ubuntu.com and give me the link here.

Comment: I don't understand...paste what? (@heemayl)

Comment: @aksub: You said portion of your comment is missing so i said you could just paste that portion and give the link so that i can have a look.

Comment: I had made a reference to you at the beginning of the following comment: "Got it. Done. But why didn't my reference to you appear on my comment as your reference to me did?" But even when copy-pasting into pastebin, it doesn't show.  Somehow it gets eraseed when I put the @ reference at the very beginning of my comment.

Comment: @aksub,  `@` is used for notification.  No need for it, when you comment to the post owner. He gets notified by default for any comment related to his post.